# Странное поведение UIScrollView вместе со StatusBar

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

Проблема в следующем, наношу на контроллер `UIScrollView` растягиваю на весь контроллер.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После чего наношу на это scroll `UIView`. прописываю констрейнты (справа, слева, сверху, снизу по нулям), а так-же ширину и высоту как у основного `UIView`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В итоге получаю такую картину

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Может кто знает, в чем может быть проблема

Серый цвет, это цвет `UIScrollView`. Так, что можно с уверенностью сказать что проблема с UIView.

Нашел проблему, я программно создаю `UINavigationBar` и задаю ему свойство `isNavigationBarHidden = true`, именно после этого приохотит эта проблема, если `UINavigationBar`убрать проблема уходит сама собой.
 Мне кажется этот отступ создает непосредственно `UIScrollView`, так-как `UIView`, находящиеся на нем скроллится.

Так же я не использую storyboard

```
        window = UIWindow.init(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    window?.backgroundColor  = UIColor.white
    window!.rootViewController = NavigationMeneger.shared.showRootViewController()
    window!.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: Покажите более детально, как вы это делаете

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в автоматическом Insets который нужно было отключить.

```
rootController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false
```

а потом уже назначать этот контролер `UINavigationController`

```
let rootNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: rootController)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Я не совсем понял, в чем проблема, но попробуйте сделать это немного иначе:*

- 1) Создайте новый `контроллер` (для пробы)
- 2) Перетащите `UIView` в этот    `контроллер`
- 3) Установите `constrains` (*лево, право, низ, верх*) и    установите
  значение `0`
- 4) `Editor` -> `Embed in`-> `Scroll view`

Это должно встроить в Ваш существующий `View` `ScrollView.`

Comment: Спасибо попробую!

Comment: К сожалению это не помогло...